Why are registrations disappearing from UnityContainer?
The Facts
I have 2 UnityContainers – one (let's call it nested) is registered inside the other (let's call it parent) using RegisterInstance() with a name so it can be resolved by it.
// Registration
nestedContainer = CreateNestedContainer(); // Creates the container and add all kinds of registrations
parentContainer.RegisterInstance("Foo", nestedContainer, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

// Resolution
var nestedContainer = parentContainer.Resolve<IUnityContainer>("Foo");

The nested container has numerous registrations (types, factories) and a BuilderStrategy extension.
The Problem
When the application starts, these containers are created and resolving and using the nested container from the parent one works just fine. However, when the app has been running for a while and the nested container is resolved again, suddenly, its registrations have disappeared and I cannot figure out why.
What I have tried
Is it really the same container?
The resolution of the nested container is done on the same thread both times and ID of the container matches I would pretty much rule out the possibility that a different container is being resolved.
Is the lifetime of the container set properly?
The nested container is registered to the parent one using RegisterInstance() with ContainerControlledLifetimeManager which means it should be a singleton.
Is it somehow possible that the registrations are garbage collected?
This sound pretty dumb, however, I wanted to check it just in case so I created a standalone app where I filled the containers, forced garbage collection and tried to resolve the instances. Unsurprisingly, everything worked just fine.
The Question
What can be causing the registrations to disappear?

Single line of code worth thousands of characters, which forms the sentence explaining it.

I've added a piece of code but I doubt it helps with the clarity all that much :)
